# Printing array in perl mason

Tags: arrays, perl, mason

I am new to Perl Mason and I am trying to print an array. I tried several ways, explored the web but nothing seems to work.

I tried -

```
my $arr = getArray();
print "Array : $arr"; # prints "Array : ARRAY(0xcd421774)"
my $size = scalar $arr;
print "Size : $size"; # prints "size ARRAY(0xcd421774)"
```

I also tried to print the first element of the array

```
print "Element : $arr[0]"; # throws error "Global symbol "@arr" requires explicit package name at ..."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `$arr` is an array reference. You need to *dereference* it with the `@{ … }` operator: `@{ $arr }` or the shorthand `@$arr`.

```
my $arr = getArray();
print "Array : @$arr";
my $size = scalar @$arr;
print "Size : $size";
```

To access one element: `${ $arr }[0]` or the shorthands `$$arr[0]` or `$arr->[0]`, of which the last form should be preferred.

To learn more about Perl references, read [`perldoc perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

Answer (score 4):

I am not familiar with Perl Mason but it seems like getArray() does **not** return an array. It might be returning an array reference. I thought that's the reason why you assign it to a scalar variable $arr, not @arr;

You can confirm this using [Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/Data-Dumper-2.151/Dumper.pm)

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $arr;
```

or [ref](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html).

```
if (ref($r) eq "ARRAY")
```

If it's indeed an array reference, you can access the **first element** like this:

```
$arr->[0];
```

**Print** the array like this:

```
print "Array : @$arr";
```

And get its **size** like this:

```
my $size = scalar @$arr;
```